# how to parse dynamic json object in Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, dynamic

I have a json object in my typescript which is returned from server side. One of the keys is dynamic. How do I parse and extract the value for that key.

```
Ex: serverResponse.detailsLMN.allList
Ex :serverResponse.detailsLMN.deleteList
```

In the above , 'LMN' is dynamic.
It can be serverResponse.detailsLMN.allList or serverResponse.detailsPQR.allList.

Assuming,
const temp = 'LMN' or 'PQR', how can I use temp to parse JSON object here.
Like :  serverResponse.details{temp}.allList

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly. But try doing

```
let data = JSON.parse(serverResponse);

((JSON.stringify(serverResponse)).includes("LMN")) ? serverResponse.detailsLMN.allList 
: serverResponse.detailsPQR.allList
```

^The above code is the same as the if statement. If you don't know the ES6 ternary conditional statement then here's a link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

To parse, simply use `JSON.parse()`. To extract the value, since I can't see the format of the output, it's better to console.log(serverResponse) the whole response and then walk through the Object in Chrome console to see how to get to your specific value.